# Setting color for numbers in code listing

Tags: listings, code

I am trying to mimic the behavior of Gedit's code highlighting in listing. For example, Gedit makes all numbers (int, float) in Python pink, but I have trouble implementing this. I tried `numberstyle` in `\lstset`, but it does not work. (In the example below, the "10" and "2" are not colored correctly)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    tabsize=4,    
    columns=fixed,
    extendedchars=false,
    breaklines=true,
    keywordstyle=\bfseries\color[HTML]{a52a2a}, 
    keywordstyle=[2]\color[HTML]{008a8c},
    commentstyle=\color[HTML]{0000ff},
    stringstyle=\color[HTML]{ff0bff},
    numberstyle=\color[HTML]{ff0bff},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python, gobble=4, basicstyle=\ttfamily]
    for i in range(10) :
        print('%d' % i**2)
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: numberstyle formats line numbers, not numbers in the code. 
There is a solution on the LaTeX forum [1] that seems to solve your problem.


  [1]: https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=22202

Comment: It solves the problem, though I have to manually add all numbers that need to be highlighted.